# Graphing with Pandas Data Frame with various columns

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, csv

[image]

I currently have the following information in a Data Frame.

I need to create a graph that compares the Budget against the Worldwide Gross of the 5 films with the highest 'porcentage de ganancia' (or income).
Nothing seems to be working.

Update:

```
datos.nlargest(5, ['Porcentaje de ganancia'])
```

```
                                 Movie    Budget  ...  Year  Porcentaje de ganancia
19          E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial  10500000  ...  1982             7551.529086
69  Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope  11000000  ...  1977             7049.072791
97                      Wolf Warrior 2  30100000  ...  2017             2891.446641
83                       The Lion King  45000000  ...  1994             2408.268616
45                               Joker  55000000  ...  2019             1953.184202
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to get the `n_largest` values for the `porcentage de ganancia` column.

```py
top_5 = df.nlargest(n=5, columns='porcentage de ganancia')
```

Then, plot using `seaborn`. Read more [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) to learn about how to customize the plot.

```py
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.scatterplot(data=top_5, x='Budget', y='Worldwide Gross', hue='Movie')
```